# Fparsec recursive grammatics throw StackOverflowException

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I've got this code

```
type Exprs = 
    | Val of float
    | Mult of Exprs  * Exprs
    | Plus of Exprs  * Exprs

let pexpr, exprRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Exprs, unit>()
let pval = pfloat |>> Val
let binaryOp s = (ws >>. pexpr.>> ws) .>>. (ws >>. str s >>. ws >>. pexpr)
let pplus = binaryOp "+" |>> Plus 
let pmuil = binaryOp "*" |>> Mult

do exprRef := choice [ attempt pmuil
                       pplus
                       pval ]

let expression = ws >>. pexpr .>> ws
```

When it evaluated it throws StackoverflowExcpetion. So the question is how can i write it without infinitie recursion?

Comment: Did you try it by hard coding the signatures?

Comment: @guy-coder I've just try it. I've rewrite `let pplus = (ws >>. pval .>> ws) .>>. (ws >>. str "+" >>. ws >>. pval) |>> Plus` and it works! Why?

Comment: oh no! My code is wrong I'm using pval instead of pexpr!

Comment: question was updated

Comment: No, my problem not solved yet. it's look like same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186230/recursive-grammars-in-fparsec and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763982/parsing-simple-types-in-fparsec

Comment: I haven't tested this and I don't normally use FParsec as my parser combinators, but try something like `Mult1 of Val` and `Mult2 of op * Exprs` With this you only look for another expression if you have an `op` and if you don't see the next `op` then you know you have reached the end of the expression.

Comment: I am trying to run your example. For `(ws >>. str s >>. ws >>. pexpr)
` what is `str` defined as?

Comment: it's `let str = pstring` and `let ws = unicodeSpaces`

Comment: Of interest: [Small Basic Parser](http://fssnip.net/le) with [Blog](http://trelford.com/blog/post/compiler.aspx) by Phillip Trelford

Comment: Are you aware of [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)?

Comment: Normally I would point to a [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) example for this, but the [F#](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#F.23) and [OCmal](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#OCaml) examples make use variations of [Lex/Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and would not be of use for an answer here. However the [ML](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#Standard_ML) version does NOT make use of Lexx/Yacc and is of interest.

Comment: Of interest: `Grammar for arithmetic expressions` in [Parsing slides](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs211/2004sp/handout/lecture05parsing.pdf)

Comment: Thank you,@guy-coder, your comments realy helpfull.

Comment: FYI I am not working to solve this with FParsec and don't plan to do an FParsec answer. If you don't require FParsec then let me know and I will do a parser combinator answer. The reason I am not doing an FParsec answer is that with FParsec arithmetic expressions using precedence are done using `OperatorPrecedenceParser`. You should be able to do that one with the example provided in `Small Basic Parser`

Comment: Also if you want a more indepth intro to parser combinators and one that leads toward the way FParsec works take a look at [The "Understanding Parser Combinators" series](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/understanding-parser-combinators.html) however that does not cover `OperatorPrecedenceParser`

Comment: To understand `OperatorPrecedenceParser` requires talking about [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), [Operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [shunting yard algorithm](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm). Also an understanding what kind of language you have, e.g. `regular`, `context free`, which parsers/compilers e.g. `recursive descent`, `parser combinator`, `Lex/Yacc`, can handle those languages and how to construct/modifty the grammar for the parser. All of this is a bit more than a simple answer.

Comment: Of interest: [Writing a MiniC-to-MSIL compiler in F# - Part 0 - Introduction](http://timjones.tw/blog/archive/2014/04/13/writing-a-minic-to-msil-compiler-in-fsharp-part-0-introduction)

Comment: Of interest: [Constructing LR(0) parsing tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Constructing_LR.280.29_parsing_tables)

Comment: Of interest: [Haskell/GADT](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) and F# request: [Add support for GADTs](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5664643-add-support-for-gadts)

Comment: Of interest: [LR to LL Grammer Conversion](https://www.andrews.edu/~bidwell/456/lr2llgram.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Parsing “x y z” with the precedence of multiply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29334253/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Recursive parsers in FParsec](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2011/07/recursive-parsers-in-fparsec.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Parsing: Lazy initialization and mutually recursive monads in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084374/parsing-lazy-initialization-and-mutually-recursive-monads-in-f)

Comment: Of interest: [Tail-recursion in FParsec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251971/tail-recursion-in-fparsec)

Comment: Of interest: [MicroCS](https://github.com/neildanson/MicroCS/tree/master/MicroCSharpCompiler) and [Building a C# compiler in F#](https://neildanson.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/building-a-c-compiler-in-f/)  Noted because it covers a more complex language.

Comment: Of interest: [Simple C# Parser](http://www.fssnip.net/lf)

Comment: Of interest: [Snippets tagged FParsec](http://www.fssnip.net/tags/FParsec)

Comment: Of interest: [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours in F# – Part I](https://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/write-yourself-a-scheme-in-48-hours-in-f-part-i/) There are 7 (VII) parts. Also see [code drop](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Write-Yourself-a-Scheme-in-d50ae449#content)

Comment: Of interest: [Adventure in parserland – parsing lambda expressions in F# – Part I](https://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/adventure-in-parserland-parsing-lambda-expressions-in-f-part-i/) There are 5 (V) parts.

Comment: Of interest: [How to convert an FParsec parser to parse whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8395139/1243762) Not specifically for this question but of use in general with FParsec.

Comment: Of interest: [Improving the readability of a FParsec parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7501532/1243762) Read the comments.

Comment: Of interest: [FParsec - Tracing a parser](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/debugging-a-parser.html#tracing-a-parser) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37590147/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Parsing expression grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) Noted because it discusses removing left recursion.

Comment: Of interest: [Notes on parsing](http://yz.mit.edu/notes/Compilers?revision=9a15a27b71a1a0475418b72c11973b134f1633d6) This gives an idea of what people who know many different parsers think about when presented with a new parser project. It should also help to understand why for many first time parser questions the answer is like, "it is not that simple" and "are you aware of ..." .

Comment: Of interest: [Grammar Tutorial](http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Teaching/CS445/grammar.html)