# FParsec only parses expr between parentheses

Tags: parsing, f#, trace, fparsec

I am coding a parser (for learning pourpuses).

I want it to parse constructions like

```
let myVar be 40 plus 2
```

and

```
let myVar be (40 plus 2)
```

With no problems... but my parser does not "understand" the former. It sees the `40` and thinks "well, it's a `Literal Numeric 40`".

When I put parentheses, my parser works great.

I am having a hard time to understand why.

Parser:

```
type value =
    | Boolean of bool
    | Numeric of float
    | String of string

type arithmetic = Sum | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow

type logic = And | Or | Equal | NotEqual | Greater | Smaller

type identifier =
    | Identifier of string

type expression =
    | Literal of value
    | Arithmetic of expression * arithmetic * expression
    | Negative of expression
    | Negation of expression
    | Logic of expression * logic * expression
    | Variable of identifier

type statement =
    | Assignment of identifier * expression
    | Print of expression
    | Read of identifier

let private ws = spaces

let private str s = pstring s .>> ws

let private pnumeric =
    pfloat
    .>> ws
    |>> fun n -> Literal (Numeric n)

let private pboolean =
    choice [
        (stringReturn "true" (Literal (Boolean true)))
        (stringReturn "false" (Literal (Boolean false)))
    ]
    .>> ws

let private pstringliteral =
    choice [
        between (pstring "\"") (pstring "\"") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '"')))
        between (pstring "'") (pstring "'") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> ''')))
    ]
    |>> fun s -> Literal (String s)

let private pidentifier =
    many1Satisfy2L isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier"
    |>> fun s -> Identifier s

let private betweenParentheses p =
    between (str "(") (str ")") p

let private pvalue =
    choice [
        pnumeric
        pboolean
    ]

let private prefixOperator (p: OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>) op prec map =
    p.AddOperator(PrefixOperator (op, ws, prec, true, map))

let private infixOperator (p: OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>) op prec map =
    p.AddOperator(InfixOperator (op, ws, prec, Associativity.Left, map))

let private oppNegation = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()
let private oppLogic = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()
let private oppArithmetic = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()
let private oppNegative = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()

prefixOperator oppNegation "not" 1 (fun x -> Negation x)
infixOperator oppLogic "is" 1 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Equal, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "isnt" 1 (fun x y -> Logic (x, NotEqual, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "and" 2 (fun x y -> Logic (x, And, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "or" 3 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Or, y))
prefixOperator oppNegative "-" 1 (fun x -> Negative x)
infixOperator oppArithmetic ">" 1 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Greater, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "<" 1 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Smaller, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "is" 2 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Equal, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "isnt" 2 (fun x y -> Logic (x, NotEqual, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "plus" 3 (fun x y -> Arithmetic (x, Sum, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "minus" 3 (fun x y -> Arithmetic (x, Sub, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "times" 4 (fun x y -> Arithmetic (x, Mul, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "divided by" 4 (fun x y -> Arithmetic (x, Div, y))
infixOperator oppArithmetic "power" 5 (fun x y -> Arithmetic (x, Pow, y))

let private negationExprParser = oppNegation.ExpressionParser
let private logicExprParser = oppLogic.ExpressionParser
let private arithmeticExprParser = oppArithmetic.ExpressionParser
let private negativeExprParser = oppNegative.ExpressionParser

oppNegation.TermParser <- choice [
    betweenParentheses negationExprParser
    pboolean
]

oppLogic.TermParser <- choice [
    betweenParentheses logicExprParser
    pboolean
]

oppNegative.TermParser <- choice [
    betweenParentheses negativeExprParser
    pnumeric
]

oppArithmetic.TermParser <- choice [
    betweenParentheses arithmeticExprParser
    pnumeric
]

let private pexpression =
    choice [
        attempt <| pstringliteral
        attempt <| negationExprParser
        attempt <| logicExprParser
        attempt <| negativeExprParser
        attempt <| arithmeticExprParser
        attempt <| (pidentifier |>> fun id -> Variable id)
    ]

let private passignment =
    pipe2 (str "let" .>> ws >>. pidentifier) (ws >>. str "be" >>. ws >>. pexpression) (fun id exp -> Assignment (id, exp))

let private pprint =
    str "print"
    >>. pexpression
    |>> fun exp -> Print exp

let private pread =
    str "read"
    >>. pidentifier
    |>> fun id -> Read id

let private pstatement =
    choice [
        passignment
        pprint
        pread
    ]

let private pline =
    skipMany (satisfy (fun c -> c = '\n' || c = ' '))
    >>. pstatement
    .>> ws

let private pcode =
    many pline

let generateAST code =
    match run pcode code with
    | Success (ast, _, _) -> sprintf "%A" ast
    | Failure (msg, _, _) -> msg
```

Usage:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%s\n" (generateAST "let b be 5 plus 7") 
    // [Assignment (Identifier "b",Literal (Numeric 5.0))]

    printfn "%s\n" (generateAST "let b be (5 plus 7)")
    // [Assignment
    //    (Identifier "b",Arithmetic (Literal (Numeric 5.0),Sum,Literal (Numeric 7.0)))]

    0
```

Comment: You might find comments to another question of interest: [Fparsec recursive grammatics throw StackOverflowException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37077358/1243762)

Comment: You have linked [this](http://www.fssnip.net/lf) in a comment. Lines 77-80 of Parser's code implement something equivalent of what I've done. Why is my code not working, if it's virtually the same thing?

Comment: When you post questions like this, please try to reduce the example showcasing your problem as far as possible. By doing so you might actually find the problem yourself or at least greatly increase the likelihood of someone else taking the time to understand and answer your question. (If you reduce this particular example code, I will try to help you!)

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf, I'm gonna do it, but right now I have sooo many things to do for work, so I have no time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [FParsec - Tracing a parser](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/debugging-a-parser.html#tracing-a-parser)

If you add the recommended FParsec tracing function to the top of your code

```
let (<!>) (p: Parser<_,_>) label : Parser<_,_> =
    fun stream ->
        printfn "%A: Entering %s" stream.Position label
        let reply = p stream
        printfn "%A: Leaving %s (%A)" stream.Position label reply.Status
        reply
```

then modify the parsers to use the trace function

```
let private pnumeric =
    (pfloat
    .>> ws
    |>> fun n -> Literal (Numeric n)) <!> "pnumeric"

let private pboolean =
    (choice [
        (stringReturn "true" (Literal (Boolean true)))
        (stringReturn "false" (Literal (Boolean false)))
    ]
    .>> ws) <!> "pboolean"

let private pstringliteral =
    (choice [
        between (pstring "\"") (pstring "\"") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '"')))
        between (pstring "'") (pstring "'") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> ''')))
    ]
    |>> fun s -> Literal (String s))  <!> "pstringliteral"

let private pidentifier =
    (many1Satisfy2L isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier"
    |>> fun s -> Identifier s) <!> "pidentifier"

let private betweenParentheses p =
    (between (str "(") (str ")") p) <!> "betweenParentheses"

let private pvalue =
    (choice [
        pnumeric
        pboolean
    ]) <!> "pvalue"

let private negationExprParser = oppNegation.ExpressionParser <!> "negationExprParser"
let private logicExprParser = oppLogic.ExpressionParser <!> "logicExprParser"
let private arithmeticExprParser = oppArithmetic.ExpressionParser <!> "arithmeticExprParser"
let private negativeExprParser = oppNegative.ExpressionParser <!> "negativeExprParser "

let private pexpression =
    choice [
        attempt <| pstringliteral
        attempt <| negationExprParser
        attempt <| logicExprParser
        attempt <| negativeExprParser
        attempt <| arithmeticExprParser
        attempt <| (pidentifier |>> fun id -> Variable id)
    ]  <!> "pexpression"

let private passignment =
    pipe2 (str "let" .>> ws >>. pidentifier) (ws >>. str "be" >>. ws >>. pexpression) (fun id exp -> Assignment (id, exp))  <!> "passignment"

let private pprint =
    (str "print"
    >>. pexpression
    |>> fun exp -> Print exp)  <!> "pprint"

let private pread =
    (str "read"
    >>. pidentifier
    |>> fun id -> Read id)  <!> "pread"

let private pstatement =
    (choice [
        passignment
        pprint
        pread
    ])   <!> "pstatement"

let private pline =
    (skipMany (satisfy (fun c -> c = '\n' || c = ' '))
    >>. pstatement
    .>> ws)   <!> "pline"

let private pcode =
    many pline  <!> "pcode"
```

and run the code you will get

```
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pcode
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pline
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pstatement
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering passignment
(Ln: 1, Col: 5): Entering pidentifier
(Ln: 1, Col: 6): Leaving pidentifier (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pexpression
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pstringliteral
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving pstringliteral (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering negationExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pboolean
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving pboolean (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving negationExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering logicExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pboolean
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving pboolean (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving logicExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering negativeExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pnumeric
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pnumeric (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving negativeExprParser (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pexpression (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving passignment (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pstatement (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pline (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Entering pline
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Entering pstatement
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Entering passignment
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving passignment (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Entering pprint
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pprint (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Entering pread
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pread (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pstatement (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pline (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 12): Leaving pcode (Ok)
[Assignment (Identifier "b",Literal (Numeric 5.0))]

(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pcode
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pline
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering pstatement
(Ln: 1, Col: 1): Entering passignment
(Ln: 1, Col: 5): Entering pidentifier
(Ln: 1, Col: 6): Leaving pidentifier (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pexpression
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering pstringliteral
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Leaving pstringliteral (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering negationExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering negationExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering pboolean
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving pboolean (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving negationExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving negationExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering logicExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering logicExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering pboolean
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving pboolean (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving logicExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving logicExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering negativeExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering negativeExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering pnumeric
(Ln: 1, Col: 13): Leaving pnumeric (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 13): Leaving negativeExprParser (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 13): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 13): Leaving negativeExprParser (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering arithmeticExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 10): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering arithmeticExprParser
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 11): Entering pnumeric
(Ln: 1, Col: 13): Leaving pnumeric (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 18): Entering betweenParentheses
(Ln: 1, Col: 18): Leaving betweenParentheses (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 18): Entering pnumeric
(Ln: 1, Col: 19): Leaving pnumeric (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 19): Leaving arithmeticExprParser (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving betweenParentheses (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving arithmeticExprParser (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pexpression (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving passignment (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pstatement (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pline (Ok)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Entering pline
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Entering pstatement
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Entering passignment
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving passignment (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Entering pprint
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pprint (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Entering pread
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pread (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pstatement (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pline (Error)
(Ln: 1, Col: 20): Leaving pcode (Ok)
[Assignment
   (Identifier "b",Arithmetic (Literal (Numeric 5.0),Sum,Literal (Numeric 7.0)))]
```

This should help you figure out your problem, but more importantly how to solve future problems with FParsec.